# iOS UIActivityViewController using UIActivityItemProvider "forgets" items

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a larger app that should be able to share multiple images.
I implemented this using UIActivityViewController and UIActivityItemProvider to have asynchronous usage of the items (so that i only have to prepare one image at a time and not have to fill the memory with all of them at once to share them).

I was "inspired" by the Apple Airdrop example:
[AirdropSample download](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2273/Introduction/Intro.html)

However when using my app to share e.g. 9 images (to camera Roll == "Save 9 images") only 4 to 7 images end up being in the camera roll, no error messages whatsoever.
If i repeat it over and over sometimes i get 5 images or 6 seemingly random.

I cannot post my app here, but i modified the above sample in a way that it will also randomly "fail" with delivering all images to the camera Roll...

If you download above sample and replace 4 files with these, it shows the problem:

APLAsyncImageViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "APLAsyncImageActivityItemProvider.h"

@interface APLAsyncImageViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

APLAsyncImageViewController.m:

```
#import "APLAsyncImageViewController.h"
#import "APLProgressAlertViewController.h"

NSString * const kProgressAlertViewControllerIdentifier = @"APLProgressAlertViewController";


@interface APLAsyncImageViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *alertWindow;
@property (strong, nonatomic) APLProgressAlertViewController *alertViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *activityPopover;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *shareImageButton;

- (IBAction)openActivitySheet:(id)sender;

@end


@implementation APLAsyncImageViewController


- (IBAction)openActivitySheet:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableArray *itemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for( int i = 0; i < 9;i++)
    {
        APLAsyncImageActivityItemProvider *aiImageItemProvider = [[APLAsyncImageActivityItemProvider alloc] init];
        [itemArray addObject: aiImageItemProvider];
    }

    //Create an activity view controller with the activity provider item. UIActivityItemProvider (AsyncImageActivityItemProvider's superclass) conforms to the UIActivityItemSource protocol
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemArray applicationActivities:nil];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        //iPhone, present activity view controller as is
        [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        //iPad, present the view controller inside a popover
        if (![self.activityPopover isPopoverVisible]) {
            self.activityPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityViewController];
            [self.activityPopover presentPopoverFromRect:[self.shareImageButton frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            //Dismiss if the button is tapped while pop over is visible
            [self.activityPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        }
    }
}
@end
```

APLAsyncImageActivityItemProvider.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface APLAsyncImageActivityItemProvider : UIActivityItemProvider
@end
```

APLAsyncImageActivityItemProvider.m:

```
#import "APLAsyncImageActivityItemProvider.h"
#import "UIImage+Resize.h"

@implementation APLAsyncImageActivityItemProvider


- (id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
{
    return [[UIImage alloc] init];
}

- (id)item
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Flower.png"];

    //CGSize imageSize;
    //imageSize.height = 1000;
    //imageSize.width = 1000;
    //image = [UIImage imageWithImage:image scaledToFitToSize:imageSize];

    return image;
}

- (UIImage *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController thumbnailImageForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType suggestedSize:(CGSize)size
{
    //The filtered image is the image to display on the other side.
    return [[UIImage alloc] init];
}

@end
```

If you execute the sample like this (Use menu item "Send Image After Preprocessing", press "SHARE" Button) it will often or mostly fail to deliver all 9 images to the camera roll.

IF you uncomment the 4 lines in "APLAsyncImageActivityItemProvider.m" that basically just scale the output image THEN it will work ALWAYS.

Can you tell me why ? I feel that if i know the answer to that riddle i can also fix my app.

Thank you,

Nils

Comment: I’m running into the same issue. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this issue is pretty simple.

There are limited number of writer threads available to use by the app, so writing too many images simulteneously may fail due to "Write Busy" error. You can verify that by trying to manually write these images using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (or corresponding Asset/Photos framework counterparts).
So, resizing images just hides the real problem because writing a smaller image takes less time.

The problem can be solved by liming the number of writers and/or retrying in case of error.
Also note that -[UIActivityItemProvider item] is a blocking call, but there are no synchronous ways to write to the gallery out of the box. This can be handled with dispatch_semaphore_wait , NSCondition, etc.
Or, in case you're using ReactiveCocoa, by simply calling waitUntilCompleted.

Answer (score 0):

I would go to say that the `[UIImage imageWithImage:image scaledToFitToSize:imageSize]` image created is GC before saved to camera roll, but I don't know what is going on in that method without the code.  That method is not a normal UIImage method, a category maybe?

### EDIT

Replace your for loop code adding to your item array with this code, and then uncomment your resize lines, and see if that works.

```
NSMutableArray *itemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for( int i = 0; i < 9;i++)
{
    UIImage *aiImage = [[[APLAsyncImageActivityItemProvider alloc] init] image];
    [itemArray addObject:aiImage];
}
```

Comment: Its a method in the sample that is able to resize images. (UIImage+Resize.h/m).

Comment: That doesn't help determine if something is being garbage collected before it is being saved.

Comment: I suspect something like that, i posted the download link to the sample above, do you have any idea how to prevent the image from being "thrown away" ? As you probably guessed i am a OBJ-C noob and 99% of my app is in C++, i only needed OBJ_C for the "Share" functionality...

Comment: Not sure how UIActivityViewController knows to call `item` to get the image.  Try to add the image to the array instead of the `APLAsyncImageActivityItemProvider` object... `[[APLAsyncImageActivityItemProvider alloc] init].image` should work.

Comment: Sorry, should be `[[[APLAsyncImageActivityItemProvider alloc] init] image]`

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for helping, but i do not understand at which point (or file) to make that modification. Just keep in mind that i want to be able to "share" an arbitrary number of DIFFERENT images in the real world app, i just hardcoded it to 9 images of the same "flower.jpg" source to not pump up the sample unnecessarily...

Comment: I tried to replace my loop with your edited code but that does not compile (It says "No visible @interface for 'APLAsyncImageActivityItemProvider' declares the selector 'image').

Comment: you need to add `- (void)image;` to your header file so that the method can be public facing.

Comment: Hello again. Hmm, are you sure you don't meant to write ...alloc] init] item] ? I could make sense of that, then the provider would be called to get the image at the time when the nsarray is constructed. I tried that and it works but it negates the sense of using a provider as the memory for all images is allocated at one point instead of allocated one after each other an processed and freed so that a minimum memory footprint is guaranteed. Please give me a hint if i completely misunderstood your path. (And sorry for my english).

Comment: @user3060868, yes sorry, you are correct, i meant alloc] init] item].  An NSArray is going to hold a pointer to the `APLAsyncImageActivityItemProvider` which then will hold a pointer to all of it's properties.  By referencing a new pointer to the image you are actually going to reclaim the memory that `APLAsyncImageActivityItemProvider` takes up.  At least, this is how I understand GC in ARC.  You are implicitly going to release that memory space.

Comment: Hi ! Ah thanks, i felt i was completely lost with "image" instead of "item"... :-)  Memory consumption -> What i need to avoid is to have all images loaded at the same time. I am *not* afraid of freeing them later, i hope hat will work with ARC or with some intelligence of my own. And i assume that (using your method) all images would be loaded in memory after i set up the array. The ImageProvider samples i saw work more like what i coded in the modded example. When i log all images are loaded fine only i wonder why they are *lost* that is my main concern. Greetings, Nils

Comment: Whoa... It looses images the same way if i try your approach... Did you actually give it a try and run the modified Airdrop Example (i know that is a lot to ask, just being curious).