# UIActivityViewController lets me share at maximum 5 entries to camera roll

Tags: ios, uikit, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to share some photos from my application to camera roll. But I can't share more than 5 photos. If I select 6 photos from my app the view controller shows the option Save 6 images, but only 5 are saved.
This is the code I'm using:

```
NSMutableArray *allEntries = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for ( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
        {
           NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/img%02d.jpg",DOCUMENTS_FOLDER, photoFolder,i]];
           [allEntries addObject:url];
        }
        UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:allEntries applicationActivities:nil];
        [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I'm testing on ios 8.3

If I select any other share option(Facebook,messages,email) all 6 photos are shared. Is this an Apple bug or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm getting this issue too; did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I’m running into the same issue. Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with iOS and has been broken for many releases. At the time of writing I am on iOS 10.1 and it is still broken. My company has reported this issue several times and followed up on it with a more direct contact. They said "We went ahead and escalated with engineering". They asked for a sample project ("Engineering is requesting a sample project that reproduces the issue and they can use to debug. Can you please add this to the radar and let me know when complete?") and I wrote up a simple project that reproduced the problem. It has since been two months and a major release with no resolution.

I recommend working around this in your user interface. You cannot attribute the bug to AAPL in your app and expect to pass app review, but you could consider hiding the Save Items option when more than 5 items are selected.

related: [iOS UIActivityViewController using UIActivityItemProvider "forgets" items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874568/ios-uiactivityviewcontroller-using-uiactivityitemprovider-forgets-items)